# jQuery UI datepicker, "disabled days" not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the following function to disable days from 2011-02-13 to 2011-02-18 in the date picker calendar:

```
function no_disabled_days(date){
               dateStr1 = '2011-02-13T00:00:00';                   
               dateStr2= '2011-02-18T00:00:00';

               disabled_start_day = new Date(dateStr1);
               disabled_end_day = new Date(dateStr2);

               if(date >= disabled_start_day && date <= disabled_end_day){
                   return [false];
               }


             return [true];

  }

$("#reserve_date").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: no_disabled_Days
});
```

For example, if **dateStr1='2011-02-13T00:00:00'**, **dateStr2='2011-02-18T00:00:00'**, the days from **2011-02-13** to **2011-02-18** are **disabled**.

Things are working fine in **Chrome** and **Firfox** browswer, however, when I test in **IE 7 and 8**, things are not working, only datepicker calendar can popup, the `disabled_days` is not disabled. Why? How to change my code to let it also working in IE 7 and 8?

By the way, the '**T00:00:00**' string is **needed** to resolve local timezone issue in Firefox,( to make the disable days working in Firefox), check out my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991824/jquery-ui-datepicker-strange-problem-happens-in-firefox)

Comment: if `00:00:00` is not needed, try removing it.

Comment: Hi, it is needed, initially, I did not use T00:00:00, then I found it causes local timezone issue problem in Firefox, only with T00:00:00, the problem can be avoid.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in IE is your format...

try this

```
alert(new Date('2011-02-13T00:00:00').getDate()); // alerts NaN, your current format
alert(new Date('2011/02/13T00:00:00').getDate()); // alerts 13
alert(new Date('02-13-2011T00:00:00').getDate()); // alerts 13
```

<sub>tested on IE 7</sub>

Comment: Yes, but if I change it to 2011/02/13T00:00:00, Firefox is not working properly. Seems there is no unique solution to make it working in Chrome, Firefox and IE 7,8 at the same time...